# In .Net, can I specify a default application wide Isolation Level?

Tags: .net, transactionscope, isolation

When I am using a `TransactionScope` object I can specify the Isoaltion Level [using the transaction options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609907/how-do-i-specify-the-database-isolation-level-to-be-used-at-a-high-level/609928#609928).

What is the default isolation level used if none is specified?

Is it possible to set an application wide default isolation level that would be used by the `TransactionScope`s?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own object to wrap the TransactionScope, setting the correct Isolation level, then use that in place of a TransactionScope.

I can't guarantee this would work, but sounds plausible.  Let me know if it does and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We just have a helper method `TransactionManager.CreateTransactionScope` which creates one with the project-wide options. It's also a useful place to encapsulate additional logic such as if there is an ambient transaction you can either use that, or create a nested transaction with compatible options, or create a new transaction, depending on what suits your application (you may want to create overloads specifying which of these behaviours are allowed).